# Django urls + React Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

i have the next djnago urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('register',views.registerPage, name="register"),
path('login',views.loginPage, name="login"),
path('logout',views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
path('',views.index),
path('createcompany',views.index),
# path('',views.index, name='home'),
path('test',views.index, name='test'),
path('admin',views.administrare_view,name='admin'),
]
```

and React route:

```html
<Router>
        <Drawer />
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="/createcompany" element={<RegisterPage />}/>
        <Route path="/test" element={<TestPage />}/>
        <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPage />}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
```

When i press the logout button it chnage the link to /logout but dosen't logout the user. If i type manually the link or i refresh the page the user is gonna to logout.
The menu dynamically created from React

```html
const menuList=[
        {
            id:1,
            text:"Profile",
            icon:<PersonIcon sx={{ color: 'gray' }} />,
            link:'/profile',
        },
        {
            id:2,
            text:'Logout',
            icon:<LogoutIcon sx={{ color: 'gray' }} />,
            link:'/logout',
        },
        
    ]
    
    
    <Tooltip title='Profile' placement='bottom' arrow enterDelay={500}>
                <IconButton
                    onClick={userAvatar_Click}
                    size="small"
                    sx={{ ml: 2 }}
                    aria-controls={open ? 'account-menu' : undefined}
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                >
                <Avatar sx={{ width: 32, height: 32 }}>M</Avatar>
            </IconButton>
            
            </Tooltip>
            <Menu
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            id='account-menu'
            open={open}
            onClose={userAvatar_Close}
            onClick={userAvatar_Close}
            PaperProps={{
                elevation: 0,
                sx: {
                  overflow: 'visible',
                  filter: 'drop-shadow(0px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.32))',
                  mt: 1.5,
                  '& .MuiAvatar-root': {
                    width: 32,
                    height: 32,
                    ml: -0.5,
                    mr: 1,
                  },
                  '&:before': {
                    content: '""',
                    display: 'block',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    right: 14,
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10,
                    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
                    transform: 'translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)',
                    zIndex: 0,
                  },
                },
              }}
            transformOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
            anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
            >
                {
                    menuList.map(item =>(
                        <MenuItem 
                        
                        onClick={()=> navigate(item.link)}
                        >
                        {item.icon}{item.text}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))
                }
            
            </Menu>
```

Log out view:

```html
def logoutUser(request):

    logout(request)

    return redirect('login')
```

How can i point from react to that django view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In full-stack app like this, **the links in the frontend is for client side only**. For logging out the user, you need to request to the server through API, to the backend link using something like fetch api or axios. For eg:

```
axios.post/get(`link to logout in the backend`)
.then(...)
.catch(...);
```

You can bind this req to onclick event on logout button and after doing this, react app sends a get/post request to the backend and user gets logged out.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it partially with your answer, but now i didn't know how to restrict the user to not using the app after that and redirect him to the login page. I also have a view to display the login page:

```html
@unauthenticated_user
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Username or password is incorrect!')
            
    context={}
    return render(request,'accounts/login.html',context)
```

and for rendering the app:

```html
@login_required(login_url='login')
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request,'accounts/blank.html')
```

The login page is hardcoded and it looks like this:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Login - Brand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css' %}">
</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-12 col-xl-10">
                <div class="card shadow-lg o-hidden border-0 my-5">
                    <div class="card-body p-0">
                        <div class="row row-cols-1 justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="p-5">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        
                                            {% if messages %}
                                                {% for message in messages %}
                                                    {% if message.tags == "success" %}
                                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                                        {{message}}
                                                    </div>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                          
                                        <h4 class="text-dark mb-4">Welcome Back!</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <form class="user" method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control form-control-user" type="text" id="exampleInputUsername" aria-describedby="usernameHelp" placeholder="Username" name="username"></div>
                                        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control form-control-user" type="password" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password"></div><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-white btn-user" type="submit">Login</button>
                                        <hr>
                                        {% if messages %}
                                                {% for message in messages %}
                                                    {% if message.tags == "error" %}
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                                        {{message}}
                                                    </div>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                    </form>
                                    <div class="text-center"><a class="small" href="forgot-password">Recuperare parola</a></div>
                                    <div class="text-center"><a class="small" href="{% url 'register' %}">Nu ai un cont? Creaza unul!</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/chart.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/bs-init.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/theme.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

After the logout i want to reach this page